# Scrapy output feed international unicode characters (e.g. Japanese chars)

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I'm a newbie to python and scrapy and I'm following the dmoz tutorial. As a minor variant to the tutorial's suggested start URL, I chose a Japanese category from the dmoz sample site and noticed that the feed export I eventually get shows the unicode numeric values instead of the actual Japanese characters.

It seems like I need to use [TextResponse](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse) somehow, but I'm not sure how to make my spider use that object instead of the base Response object.

1. How should I modify my code to show the Japanese chars in my output?
2. How do I get rid of the square brackers, the single quotes, and the 'u' that's wrapping my output values?

Ultimately, I want to have an output of say

**オンラインショップ** (these are japanese chars)

instead of the current output of

**[u'\u30aa\u30f3\u30e9\u30a4\u30f3\u30b7\u30e7\u30c3\u30d7']** (the unicodes)

If you look at my screenshot, it corresponds to cell C7, one of the text titles.

Here's my spider (identical to the one in the tutorial, except for different start_url):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from dmoz.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "dmoz.org"
   allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/World/Japanese/"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

settings.py:

```
FEED_URI = 'items.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

output screenshot:
http://i55.tinypic.com/eplwlj.png (sorry I don't have enough SO points yet to post images)

Comment: The scraping is working, the issue is just with how the values get written out to disk. How are you calling Scrapy to run the code?

Comment: @Thomas I think the problem was just that the text was embedded in lists. Once I extracted them from the lists the unicode chars displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scrape the text from the page it is stored in Unicode.

What you want to do is encode it into something like UTF8.

```
unicode_string.encode('utf-8')
```

Also, when you extract the text using your selector, it is stored in a list even if there is only one result, so you need to pick the first element.

Comment: thanks I did eventually realize that they were stored in lists and ended up using `if item['title']:
                item['title'] = item['title'].pop()` to extract them. As for the encoding, after I extracted they automatically turned into the correct characters.

Comment: Btw, how would I swap in TextResponse for Response if I needed to?

Comment: @fortuneRice I also have the same issue while parsing a tamil content. Please share your code which solves this issue. (I couldnot understand where you used .pop() )

Comment: @Mugunth the scraped text is stored in a list data structure. The .pop() is used to extract the item from the list. Hope it helps.

Comment: @fortuneRice sorry to bother you again. I dont understand how to use .pop() from the list to store the data into csv. for example: i have parse definition similar to following: // for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items // It would be helpful if you could let me know where this .pop() should go in this code.

Comment: @Mugunth you can start a new question, I'll try to get to it soon, that's if no one beats me to it answering your question :)

Comment: for me, i get the correct output without getting the first element of the 'list'.